# Logic behind the polarity score calculated by TEXTBLOB?

Tags: python-2.7, sentiment-analysis, textblob

How does textblob calculate polarity in sentiment analysis? What logic does it follow and can we change the logic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

TextBlob used a classifier to predict the polarity of a sentence. By default it uses the Movie-Review data set. You can train it using your own training model.